# Unable to install Angular cli on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install angular/cli on my ubuntu system but I am getting the error as in the image 
[image: error]
  I have tried following Commands as well

```
npm cache clean 
npm cache clean --force
and multiple npm i or in general removing the 
lock file and deleting node_modules.
```

I followed many blogs but still can't resolve the issue.
can someone help me with that?
Thank you.

Comment: try to ```npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"``` or if didn't work try to update your npm.

Comment: it seems that you are using an old version of npm. Try to upgrade it npm update -g npm

Comment: @FatemeFazli ,JEY I have used both the solutions  you have given don't know exactly which got worked but its working fine for me 
Thank you both